# noVNC loaded from Apache causes corrupted cursors

Tags: apache, nas

I've got a NAS box with x11vnc and websockify running on it. If I connect to the vnc by loading noVNC from novnc.com, everything works perfectly. If I connect to the vnc by loading noVNC from the NAS box through Apache webserver, the cursors appear as a single horizontal line.

I don't know anything about Apache and am currently using only the default settings.

Could it be something to do with differences between the novnc.com noVNC and the zip-package noVNC or is it more likely to be a setting in Apache?

**Update**

Some more testing revealed this issue occurs in both Chrome (38.0.2125.101 m) and Firefox (32.0.3), but not Internet Explorer. However, in IE's case, it simply didn't support local cursors to begin with and rendered with Local Cursor turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was driving me nuts too. It appears to be a bug in the latest version of noVNC.

The noVNC site contains a number of different noVNC versions:
https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/tree/gh-pages

The one you will get by default ([noVNC/vnc.html](http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/noVNC/vnc.html)) is almost a year old. By comparison, the "latest" version ([noVNC-latest/vnc.html](http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/noVNC-latest/vnc.html) ) is much more recent, and is the one that you have on your web server.

Most likely you'll find the more recent version does not display correctly either.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't notice there were multiple branches on git. I may be a programmer, but I _still_ don't understand github most of the time :/ I'll see if I can find the version he uses on the website in those branches. Thanks again! :D

Comment: The [app branch](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/tree/app) seems to work just fine, even if the theme isn't quite as pretty as the later versions ;)

Comment: The reason the "app" branch works OK is that it's older than the introduced bug. The last commit was in 2012. The most recent commit that doesn't have the bug appears to be [fb64ed213584423475a262631b6be2e2a157c628](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/tree/fb64ed213584423475a262631b6be2e2a157c628), from May 2014. I'm using that instead.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't feel like going through each commit to find the latest version without the bug, but you've done it for me! :D